# How to color a landscape?

Tags: 3d-view

I have created a landscape using the ANT Landscape add-on

Now how can I color it?.I don't want to add a texture.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a way to create a procedurally generated terrain texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using Cycles add a diffuse shader or if your using Blender render then just got to the material tab and change it to the colour you desire. If your talking about having it in the view port then scroll down in the Material Tab and click the View port shading,  then just select your colour. If this Answers your question then please tick the arrow beside the answer so that it says the question has been answered.